# What are the limitations of dynamic casting?

Tags: c++, casting

I need to use casting in my program. I have in my code heading, in my base class

```
scSupervisor* msSupervisor;    ///< My Supervisor
```

and I want to create an accessor function in the same header, in the derived class

```
Supervisor* Supervisor_Get(void){ return (Supervisor*)msSupervisor;}
                                       //dynamic_cast<Supervisor*>(msSupervisor);}
```

As shown, the static casting compiles and runs fine. However, if I change to the dynamic cast version (shown commented) I am presented with the error message:

```
cannot dynamic_cast '((Core*)this)->Core::<anonymous>.scCore::msSupervisor' (of type 'class scSupervisor*') to type 'class Supervisor*' (target is not pointer or reference to complete type)
                  dynamic_cast<Supervisor*>(msSupervisor);}
                                                        ^
```

In my eyes, it is a pointer. Do I do something illegal?

Comment: Does the code see the full declaration of `Supervisor` at this point? See my emphasis on the error message: _"target is not pointer or reference to **complete type**"_.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `dynamic_cast<T>` has multiple limitations, the one that is relevant to your situation is described in section 5.2.7.1 of the C++ standard:

> The result of the expression `dynamic_cast<T>(v)` is the result of converting the expression `v` to type `T`. `T` shall be a pointer or reference to a complete class type, or “pointer to cv `void`.”

Note the requirement for the class type to be *complete* in the description above.

In your case, `T` is `Supervisor*`, which, according to the error message, is not a pointer to a complete class (i.e. a pointer to a class that has been forward-declared, but not fully specified).

Including a header file for `Supervisor` will fix this problem.

Comment: I did have a #include "scSupervisor.h" in my head. Later, however, I also had "class scSupervisor; class Supervisor;" maybe this confused the compiler? Anyhow, I moved the function body to the .cpp file, and everything works fine.

Comment: @katang When this error happens for code in the header, the most likely cause is that a header guard made the definition invisible. Moving the code to cpp file often fixes this problem, because definitions from both headers are available.